# MVC 5 SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error, with [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I'm having trouble setting up Authorization in MVC 5. I have a brand new MVC 5 website with Individual User Accounts and an SQL Server database with the five aspNet... tables.

I can login locally, it all works fine on my local server and I can even login the production database from my local website when I point my local connection string at the production server but I can't  login from the website on the production server,

**I get the following error:**

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

The error only happens when I use [Authorize] on an Action where I then have to login, if I remove [Authorize] the Action and database work fine.

Any ideas

**Edit**

Just for clarity, the SQL Server is on one of Arvixe servers, and the website is at Godaddy  here is my connection string

```
<add name="mysiteEntities"
connectionString="metadata =
res://*/Models.mysite.csdl|res://*/Models.mysite.ssdl|res://*/Models.mysite.msl;
provider = System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string ='
data source = xxxxx.arvixe.com;
Initial Catalog = mysite;
User ID = xxxxxx;
Password = xxxxxxx'"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am unable to login from Godaddy with this string but if I use this string on my local computer I can login.

I also have a number of websites set up with the same configuration in MVC 4 which work fine.

Comment: Check your connection string is correct. I don't think it is. The Authorize annotation is causing the application to try and connect to the ASP Identity tables in order to authenticate the user. It cant reach the database.

Comment: If I use the same connection string locally it connects to the online database and I can log in, it also works on the other tables, if I remove Authorize the rest of the tables work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out but it let me to a new question that I wave a work around for. For this question I had the wrong base connection referenced in here.

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```

The problem now is I need two connection strings to connect. One for Authorisation as MVC5 wants a **Code First** connection string but the rest of my code is **Database First**

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue; however, I wrongly assumed it to be that I was not using EF and SQL Server, but Telerik Data Access around Oracle 11g. What fixed it for me was to remove the RoleManager module in the config file, as per this article (http://blog.luppes.com/2013/12/08/mvc5-authentication-roles-failure/)

So, to paraphrase that link for posterity, it was:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This did it for me!